# Error on login form

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, servlets

I am new to java servlets.
I googled for how to build simple login form with validation against mysql database. I have made so much changes and still have the following error for some reason.

The following error type:

```
HTTP Status 404 - /LoginServlet

type Status report

message /LoginServlet

description The requested resource is not available.
Apache Tomcat/7.0.57
```

Here all my jsp pages and java objects and web.xml:

**index.jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Login Page</title>
</head>
<body>
<center>
<h1>Login Details</h1>
<form action="/LoginServlet" method="POST">
<br/>Username:<input type="text" name="username">
<br/>Password:<input type="password" name="password">
<br/><input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

**Welcome.jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"  
  pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>  
<html>  
<head>  
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">  
<title>Welcome <%=session.getAttribute("name")%></title>  
</head>  
<body>  
<h3>Login successful!!!</h3>  
<h4>
Hello,
<%= session.getAttribute("name")%>
</h4>  
</body>  
</html>
```

**LoginServlet.java**
    package com.servlet;

```
import java.io.IOException;  
import java.io.PrintWriter;  

import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;  
import javax.servlet.ServletException;  
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;  
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;  
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;  
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

import com.logindao.LoginDao;

public class LoginServlet extends HttpServlet {  

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;  

public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {    

    response.setContentType("text/html");    
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();    

    String n=request.getParameter("username");    
    String p=request.getParameter("password");   

    HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);  
    if(session!=null)  
    session.setAttribute("username", n);  

    if(LoginDao.validate(n, p)){    
        RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("welcome.jsp");    
        rd.forward(request,response);    
    }    
    else{    
        out.print("<p style=\"color:red\">Sorry username or password error</p>");    
        RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp");    
        rd.include(request,response);    
    }    

    out.close();    
   }    
}
```

**LoginDao.java**

```
package com.logindao;

import java.sql.*;

public class LoginDao {  
    public static boolean validate(String name, String pass) {          
        boolean status = false;  
        Connection conn = null;  
        PreparedStatement pst = null;  
        ResultSet rs = null;  

    String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/";  
    String dbName = "form";  
    String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";  
    String userName = "root";  
    String password = "password";  
    try {  
        Class.forName(driver).newInstance();  
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url + dbName, userName, password);  

        pst = conn.prepareStatement("select * from login where user=? and password=?");  
        pst.setString(1, name);  
        pst.setString(2, pass);  

        rs = pst.executeQuery();  
        status = rs.next();  

    } catch (Exception e) {  
        System.out.println(e);  
    } finally {  
        if (conn != null) {  
            try {  
                conn.close();  
            } catch (SQLException e) {  
                e.printStackTrace();  
            }  
        }  
        if (pst != null) {  
            try {  
                pst.close();  
            } catch (SQLException e) {  
                e.printStackTrace();  
            }  
        }  
        if (rs != null) {  
            try {  
                rs.close();  
            } catch (SQLException e) {  
                e.printStackTrace();  
            }  
        }  
    }  
    return status;  
   }  
}
```

**Web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>

<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
                      http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
  version="3.0">

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>login</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.servlet.LoginServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>login</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/LoginServlet</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here:

```html
<form action="/LoginServlet" method="POST">
              ^ means absolute path
```

Change it to a proper form using EL:

```html
<form action="${request.contextPath}/LoginServlet" method="POST">
```

---

In your `doPost` method, if you're already using this:

```
RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("...");
rd.forward(request,response);
```

There's no need to use the writer of the response:

```
PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
//...
out.print("<p style=\"color:red\">Sorry username or password error</p>");
//...
out.close();
```

These lines using `out` should be removed from your code.

Also, please [stop using scriptlets](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3177733/1065197). Use EL + JSTL to achieve the same result:

```html
<!-- <title>Welcome <%=session.getAttribute("name")%></title> -->
<!-- Retrieve it directly from any scope -->
<!-- <title>Welcome ${name}</title> -->
<!-- If you want to make sure it is retrieved from session scope -->
<title>Welcome <c:out value="${sessionScope.name}" /></title>
</head>  
<body>  
<h3>Login successful!!!</h3>
<h4>
<!-- similar here -->
<!--
Hello, <%= session.getAttribute("name")%>
-->
Hello, <c:out value="${sessionScope.name}" />
```

Comment: I still have the same error:

HTTP Status 404 - /LoginServlet

type Status report

message /LoginServlet

description The requested resource is not available.
Apache Tomcat/7.0.57

Answer (score 1):

Unless your application is deployed as the root application, all the URLs to resources of the application should start with the *context path* of the application (the root application's context path is the empty string).

Typically, if your war file is `myWebApp.war`, the app is living under `/myWebApp`, and all the URLs should thus start with `/myWebApp`.

Your form action is `/LoginServlet`, so it fails to fill this constraint.

Use the JSTL, and define the action as

```
<form action="<c:url value='/LoginServlet' />"
```

The `c:url` tag will prepend the context path, whatever it is.

Comment: I still have the same error:

HTTP Status 404 - /LoginServlet

type Status report

message /LoginServlet

description The requested resource is not available.
Apache Tomcat/7.0.57

Comment: Have you correctly installed the JSTL jar files, and declared the use of the core library in the JSP? What's the HTML source (in the browser) of the form?

Comment: Yes i downloaded JSTL jar file and drop it in WEB-INF.
But still the same error type !!!
Any suggestions ???
Please help me..

Comment: Yes, I have a suggestion: answer my questions. Have you declared the use of the core library in the JSP? What's the HTML source (in the browser) of the form?

Comment: I am not so sure i am understanding what you say, i am really new to all of this, but from what i understand i declared the use of the core library in my jsp file like this:
Just add this to jsp file:
<%@  taglib  prefix="c"  uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>

Also i don't understand your second question..

Thanks a lot for helping me !

Comment: When you right-click in your browser and click "View HTML source", what does the code of the form look like?

Comment: Now for some reason i can't get to the index.jsp and here is the error:
HTTP Status 500 - The absolute uri: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this application

type Exception report

message The absolute uri: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this application

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

Answer (score 0):

You servlet is not found in the absolute path you requested the `<form action>` attribute . I suggest you to get the path using `contextPath` as suggessted by @Luggi.

This temporary soultion should work ,

```
<form action="<c:url value='./LoginServlet'>"
```

as it will search for the servlet in the packages that are created under the `src` package.

And also avoid using the scriplets as they are not suggested over the decade. Please see [How to avoid Java code in JSP files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files)

Hope this helps